# Trigger with boolean not working

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to display a value in the ListView depending on the state of the boolean, but it does not work. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<ListView x:Name="LiViTest" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,0.01,0,0" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header=" numb " >
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TxtTest" />
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=boolTest}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter TargetName="TxtTest" Property="Text" Value="test false"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=boolTest}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter TargetName="TxtTest" Property="Text" Value="test true"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate> 
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine, or it would work just fine for you if you had the correct data structure. To make this work, the `boolTest` property must be a `bool` property *of an item inside the `GridView`*.

Alternatively, if you are trying to data bind to a single `boolTest` property that resides *outside* the `GridView`, then you'll need to use a different `Binding`. However, that will really depend on how you set your `DataContext`.

Assuming that you have an instance of some class that has the required `boolTest` property already set as the `Window.DataContext`, you could then use a `RelativeSource Binding` to access it:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.boolTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="TxtTest" Property="Text" Value="test false"/>
</DataTrigger>
```